# All pages under ssl except index.html

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I use `.htaccess` to redirect the pages to HTTP and not to HTTPS.

The code is :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Now, I want all pages other than the index to redirect to HTTPS.
All except `index.html`.

How can i do this with `.htaccess`?

Comment: Does the URL always contain `index.html` when requesting the home page, or is `example.com/` a possible URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
# Redirect all pages, except homepage to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule !^(index\.html)?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

# Redirect homepage to HTTP
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(index\.html)?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

Test with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid caching issues.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing.